# Is it possible to declare an Objective-C method outside a class?

Tags: objective-c, c, methods

I know that you can declare a C function outside of a class, but is it possible to declare a Objective-C method outside of a class?

Example:

```
// Works
void printHelloC()
{
    NSLog(@"Hello.");
}

// Error
-(void) printHelloOC
{
    NSLog(@"Hello.");
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        printHelloC();
        [self printHelloOC];// 'self' obviously would not work but you get the idea
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends. You can do something similar with method adding at runtime:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

void myCustomMethod(id self, SEL _cmd, id arg1, id arg2)
{
    NSLog(@"This is a test, arg1: %@, arg2: %@", arg1, arg2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Class NSObjClass = [NSObject class];

    class_addMethod(NSObjClass, @selector(myNewMethod::), (IMP) myCustomMethod, "v@:@@");

    NSObject myObject = [NSObject new];

    [myObject myNewMethod:@"Hi" :@"There"];

    [myObject release];

    return 0;
}
```

But that is about it outside of a @class construct, and it really just covers up what happens with a category.

Comment: Good answer, but your method name is a bit of a misnomer, since it is actually a method not a selector

Answer (score 6):

You can use a *category* for this.

**As an instance method:**

```
@interface NSObject (MONStuff)
- (void)printHelloOC;
@end

@implementation NSObject (MONStuff)
- (void)printHelloOC
{
  NSLog(@"Hello.");
}
@end

// in use:

NSObject * obj = ...;
[obj printHelloOC];
```

**As a Class method:**

```
@interface NSObject (MONStuff)
+ (void)printHelloOC;
@end

@implementation NSObject (MONStuff)
+ (void)printHelloOC
{
  NSLog(@"Hello.");
}
@end

// in use:

[NSObject printHelloOC];
```

Of course, you must associate that with a class - so it's not *exactly* the same as you posted, but it's a close definition + declaration separate from the formal class declaration.

Comment: A category simply extends a class - by definition any methods declared in the category are in a class...

Comment: Your new method is an `NSString` method.  That's not outside a class - that's *inside* `NSString`!

Comment: +1. Categories extend the class with methods written outside the class. That's the *whole purpose* of using categories, after all!

Comment: That's true, but it's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: Thanks Alex. @Carl Yes, I posted the category because this is one common means to extend an existing class. Do you want answer the question in a pedantic manner, or a practical manner? In many cases, this 'external' method is a practical means to accomplish what you need. Some people will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A method without an associated class is a meaningless concept. Functions, as you've noted, are just fine.

Comment: Not necessarily true. You could have a selector that performs specific code independent of what the object is, as long as it does a certain task. That's the reasoning behind protocols.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - to do what you describe surely you define a *category* on `NSObject`?

Comment: @CRD not necessarily, you can do the same thing with method addition (see my answer). Which basically is a more complex way of doing what a category does.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible - you will need to either use global C functions or class (+) methods.

Comment: It is possible, the Objective-C runtime allows you to add methods to a class even while the program is executing. It even allows you to create whole new classes. You can define an Objective-C method implementation and then associate that method with a class and a selector.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed possible to create classes dynamically. It is not the question, however. The question is whether it is possible to define and execute Objective-C methods a-la global C functions (or, say, globally scoped JavaScript closures). It is not possible. Objective-C methods must be defined as part of a class (class or instance scoped).

Answer (score -1):

Objective c functions are always associated with a class. If you mean you want to use an objective-c function without instantiating a class, you can of course write a class method (notice the plus sign instead of the usual hyphen)

```
@interface Test

+ (void)aClassMethod;

@end
```

then you can call it by calling

```
[Test aClassMethod];
```

Comment: Not always true. If you use method swizzling for example, you can add a function to multiple classes with multiple selectors!

Comment: Perhaps... but method swizzling is a pretty advanced concept, and definitely not something that you should without careful consideration.

Comment: It isn't that complex, you simply include the runtime, create your function, and add the method to the class with a selector. It doesn't take a rocket scientist to do, and swapping method implementations is just as easy.